# проблемы с пагинацией товаров в интернет-магазине написанном на Django и bootstrap

Tags: python, django, bootstrap4

создаю главную страницу интернет магазина, и столкнулся с таким вопросом:
  в представленном ниже views.py показанно как выводятся товары на главной странице, и что при переходе к конкретной категории работает пагинация, и выводятся по 3 товара на страницу. проблема в том что не могу понять как мне вывести  такую же логику при просмотре всех товаров из всех категорий.
прошу объяснить как в данном случае я могу поступить

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)

    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products_list = products.filter(category=category)
        paginator = Paginator(products_list, 3)

        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
        except:
            page = 1

        try:
            products = paginator.page(page)
        except():
            products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,
                   })
```

Comment: В Django есть прекрасное [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) generic представление с атрибутом `paginate_by`.

Comment: не могли бы вы объяснить как всю эту вью мне исполнить в виде класса?

Comment: @GeorgePotapov Вам нужно чтобы из каждой категории показывалось по 3 товара? Или ещё, чтобы у каждой категории была своя независимая пагинация по товарам?